# Paradox in ring theory -- what am I missing?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I saw somewhere the following exercise:

*Give example of prime ideal in a ring which is not maximal*

the answer was this:

Let $R$ be our Ring and $I$ ideal such 
$$ R = {Z}[{X}] $$
$$ I = (x) $$ 
which means $I$ generated by $x$ which is all the polynomials in $R$ with zero free coefficient.

It was shown then, by First isomorphism theorem that : $$Z[X] / I \cong Z$$

Now, because $Z$ is not a field, but rather only Integral domain, then according to the theorem  $I$ is indeed Prime ideal which is not maximal ideal.

But ....

As we know $Z[X]$ is Principal ideal domain thus according to other theorem:
*every nonzero prime ideal is maximal*

So if $I=(x)$ is ideal in $R$ it means I is maximal.

Why I came to this contradiction, what am I missing ?

Comment: Perhaps you were thinking of the fact that $K[x]$ is a principal ideal domain if $K$ is a *field*.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Whereas $\mathbb{Z}$ is a principal ideal domain, $\mathbb{Z}[X]$ is not: for instance, the ideal $(2,X)$ is not generated by a single element.

Comment: thanks...don't know why I was so sure $Z[x]$ is principal ideal domain...

Comment: However $\mathbb{Z}[X]$ is a nice example of a UFD.  Polynomials rings with coefficients in a PID, as you see, are not PIDs, but polynomial rings over UFDs are again UFDs.

Comment: Ah yes, good old $(2, x) \subset \Bbb Z[x]$!